# No module named 'social_django'

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models

I have installed django and tried running the below command
pip install social-auth-app-django
But am still getting an error while installing the social auth.

```
    Installing build dependencies ... error
    error: subprocess-exited-with-error
    × pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
    │ exit code: 1
    ╰─> [41 lines of output]
    Collecting setuptools!=60.9.0,>=40.6.0
    Using cached setuptools-65.5.0-py3-none-any.whl (1.2 MB)
    Collecting wheel
    Using cached wheel-0.37.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (35 kB)
  Collecting cffi>=1.12
    Using cached cffi-1.15.1.tar.gz (508 kB)
    Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
    Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
    error: subprocess-exited-with-error

    python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
    exit code: 1
```

I have searched on net, but not able to get a solution.
Any help is appreciated!!

Comment: can you run it with `pip install -v social-auth-app-django social-auth-app-django` and give us that full output, because that block you've provided doesn't really give us what is failing **(like at all)** .. also what' python version are you using?

Comment: Try after upgrading pip

Comment: Yep I tried upgrading the pip and it worked. Thanks !!